# Get value of multiple generated controls

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a DataBase with for example 3 columns.

ID (int), name (Varchar), date (Datetime).

Let's say, I want to add a row into this DataBase via my Application and I want different controls for different DataTypes.
So for `ID` I want a TextBox with Upper/Down Arrows. For `name` a simple TextBox and for `Date` a DatePicker.

That's easy, i call the SchemaTable from my DataBase into a loop and make an if statement to check if DataType = `System.String or System.DateTime or System.Int32`.

So that's it.

Now what to do when i press enter? The controls are dynamically added and all have different Properties. But i need the value from all of them, to save this into the DataBase.

My idea is, looping through the controls `Content Property` and gets the value.
But many Controls have different Content Properties. 
For example a DatePicker has the Box + the Pick-Icon.

How are u guys gonna solve this ?

If all were TextBoxes (which they are for now) i can get the Text Property from all of them with this code:

```
List<TextBox> textboxes = new List<TextBox>();
textboxes = sp.Children.OfType<TextBox>().ToList();
string query = "INSERT INTO " + myTable + " (";

for (int i = 0; i < textboxes.Count; i++)
{
    if (i < textboxes.Count - 1)
        query += textboxes[i].Name + ",";
    else
        query += textboxes[i].Name;
}

query += ") VALUES (";

for (int i = 0; i < textboxes.Count; i++)
{
    if (textboxes[i] == null)
    {
        textboxes[i].Text = "0";
    }

    if (i < textboxes.Count - 1)
        query += "'" + textboxes[i].Text + "',";
    else
        query += "'" + textboxes[i].Text + "')";
}
```

but this can't work now, because of different Controls which can be changed every time so they are never static and I HAVE TO generate the controls.

This is the Code how I add the controls (only show you DatePicker and normal TextBox for better understanding)

```
foreach (DataRow field in schemaTable.Rows)
        {
            if (field.Field<String>("ColumnName") != "id")
            {
                if (field["DataType"].ToString() == "System.DateTime")
                {
                    DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker();
                    MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.HintAssist.SetHint(datePicker,
                        UppercaseFirst(field.Field<String>("ColumnName")));
                    MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.HintAssist.SetIsFloating(datePicker, true);
                    datePicker.Margin = new Thickness(5);
                    datePicker.Name = field.Field<string>("ColumnName");
                    datePicker.Tag = field.Field<Boolean>("AllowDBNull");
                    sp.Children.Add(datePicker);
                }
                else
                {
                    TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
                    MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.HintAssist.SetHint(textBox, UppercaseFirst(field.Field<String>("ColumnName")));
                    MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.HintAssist.SetIsFloating(textBox, true);
                    textBox.Margin = new Thickness(5);

                    textBox.Name = field.Field<String>("ColumnName");
                    textBox.Tag = field.Field<Boolean>("AllowDBNull");

                    sp.Children.Add(textBox);
                }


            }
        }
```

Comment: Did you already work with the MVVM pattern? It would be a good starting point for *whatever you want to do with WPF* and most of the good answers for WPF related questions will be based on MVVM - so if you don't know / use it yet, you should start learning about it.

Comment: yea i always failing at learning mvvm. Waiting for a dude who works on a mvvm pattern because he will made some tutorials about it. So yea But no im working in code-behind. And i dont understand how this will work in mvvm because in mvvm u have to code properties or not? And i dont have the same properties because I can have 1 column in my database or 2 or 10. It's not like "i have this this and this forever". So I can't make "static"  properties then (with static i mean they are hard-coded not the static property".

Comment: Admitted, MVVM won't magically do the work for you. But it can help with the separation of concerns. You can focus on translating your SchemaTable query to a data model in your application, then translating your datamodel into an insert statement and you can separately focus on displaying your data model - it's just an opportunity to solve the puzzle step by step instead of going from database to user interface in a single huge bulk of complexity.

Comment: Have you tried creating your own control, that, given the database row will create the inner control and handle values and such?
MVVM will help a lot in this cases, since you can use components for each type of object you pass in a list and the model will be updated by these controls themselves via Data Bindings.
But you can do this with pure data bindings and a intelligent control that will create it editor for each type of data

Comment: Without knowing your application and why you HAVE TO generate the controls - couldn't you create a list of controls at the time you generate them & iterate through that list using GetType() to check the type.

Comment: @PaulF the thing is, that the code don't know which and how much controls there are. Because if I add a column into the DataBase with the DataType DATETIME then the Application have automaticly added a DatePicker control to my "Add to Database"-Method. That is what i mean with "i have to". Or for INT a numeric TextBox, etc.

Comment: So in your "Add To Database" method you add a reference to the control you created in a list that you maintain - you could even make your own class that has a fields for Column name, a reference to the control & a field that indicates the datatype - so if you are using a textbox for integers, doubles & strings - you know how to convert the data. Then you could iterate through the list to create your query & add the appropriate values.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear. If you have 3 columns and ID is incremental, use below code:

```
foreach (var row in textboxes )
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {

        string saveQuery = "INSERT into " + myTable+ " (name, date) VALUES (@name, @date)";
        using (SqlCommand querySave = new SqlCommand(saveQuery))
        {
            querySave.Connection = connection;

            querySave.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = (row == null) ? 0 : row.Text;
            querySave.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;

            connection .Open();
            querySave.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection .Close();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I definitely agree that the OP should use `SqlParameter` instead of building the values into the command, but I think this answer is missing a lot of the things mentioned in the question (handling different types of controls for different data types)

Comment: Please explain scenario more clear... 
For example you created 'Windows Form Application' that can have dynamic elements? then you need to save its data?

Comment: You have `foreach (var row in textboxes)` thing is, that I don't have only textboxes. I got DatePicker etc. and need the value from all of them.

Comment: I edit the code how I generate the controls. Maybe u will understand more know.